# Can't drop table on cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE messenger.invoice (
    fb_invoice_id text PRIMARY KEY,
    cmz_invoice_id text,
    domain text,
    page_id text,
    resend int,
    status text,
    time int,
    transfer_slip text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

when I want to drop this table

```
drop table messenger.invoice
```

Console show error like this

> ServerError: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError

*Edit* add log

```
INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2020-04-04 09:02:35,600 MigrationManager.java:466 - Drop table 'messenger/invoice'
ERROR [MigrationStage:1] 2020-04-04 09:02:35,601 CassandraDaemon.java:229 - Exception in thread Thread[MigrationStage:1,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: null
 at io.netty.util.Recycler$WeakOrderQueue.<init>(Recycler.java:225) ~[netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
 at io.netty.util.Recycler$DefaultHandle.recycle(Recycler.java:180) ~[netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
 at io.netty.util.Recycler.recycle(Recycler.java:141) ~[netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
 at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree$Builder.recycle(BTree.java:839) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree$Builder.build(BTree.java:1092) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate.build(PartitionUpdate.java:587) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate.maybeBuild(PartitionUpdate.java:577) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate.holder(PartitionUpdate.java:388) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.AbstractBTreePartition.unfilteredIterator(AbstractBTreePartition.java:177) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.AbstractBTreePartition.unfilteredIterator(AbstractBTreePartition.java:172) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate$PartitionUpdateSerializer.serialize(PartitionUpdate.java:779) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation$MutationSerializer.serialize(Mutation.java:393) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.add(CommitLog.java:249) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.applyInternal(Keyspace.java:585) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:462) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation.apply(Mutation.java:227) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation.apply(Mutation.java:232) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation.apply(Mutation.java:241) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at java.util.Collections$SingletonList.forEach(Collections.java:4822) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.mergeSchema(SchemaKeyspace.java:1298) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.mergeSchemaAndAnnounceVersion(SchemaKeyspace.java:1282) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager$1.runMayThrow(MigrationManager.java:535) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
 at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

I'm very new to cassandra and I tried very hard to find the way to fix this problem. Now I read a lot of post and some post suggest to restart service but some post point that this structure problem may cause restart failed. I'm very worry because this happen in production environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to look to the system.log on the server side

Comment: @AlexOtt I add log from server in original post. Please view and suggest.